# How to fix Perl CPAN module error: version 0.82 required, this is only version 0.78?

Tags: perl, cpan, makemaker

Whether I use CPAN or install manually, every time I try to run "perl Makefile.PL" to build a makefile for a Perl module, I get the following error:

ERROR from evaluation of Makefile.PL: Can't locate object method "new" via package "CPAN::Meta" at /usr/lib/perl5/5.8.8/ExtUtils/MM_Any.pm line 1199

The CPAN::Meta module is installed, so I'm completely stumped on this one.

When run: `perl -MCPAN::Meta -e1` it returns me the error:

> version 0.82 required--this is only version 0.78 at /usr/lib/perl5/5.8.8/CPAN/Meta/Converter.pm line 12.

Comment: what changed? (assuming you were able to do this at some point in the past)

Comment: This is on a shared machine where I don't have the root password.  This is the first time I've been asked to install a module on this specific machine.  Could it be as simple as permissions?

Comment: Which version of ExtUtils::MakeMaker do you have?

Comment: does "perl -MCPAN::Meta -e1" return any errors?

Comment: It says "version version 0.82 required--this is only version 0.78 at /usr/lib/perl5/5.8.8/CPAN/Meta/Converter.pm line 12."

Answer (score 1):

It seems that when installing ExtUtils::MakeMaker, version.pm (which is bundled inside EU::MM) was not upgraded. You need to upgrade it manually. root is required for this if you don't use local::lib.

Comment: version.pm says that its version number is 0.88, and I believe that is the latest version available.  Does it still need to be upgraded?

Comment: From your error message, you have version.pm 0.78. How do you check it's version? P.S. It is possible that you have 2 variants of version.pm installed.

Comment: I think you're right.  It looks like I also have an older version in /usr/lib64/.  Why would modules in /usr/lib/ reference files in lib64?  Are some of them just symbolic links to the 64 bit versions?

Answer (score 0):

I just had this same problem, here is a solution with description:

I was doing a "**cpan Bundle::CPAN**" which failed. When I re-ran I found that cpan was now broken and I couldn't install any modules. Worst still, "**perl Makefile.PL**" was also dying with the same error:

**Can't locate object method "new" via package "CPAN::Meta" at /usr/lib/perl5/5.8.8/ExtUtils/MM_Any.pm line XXXX**

When testing the CPAN::Meta module directly, I found the Parse::CPAN::Meta version was too old:
**perl -MCPAN::Meta**
**Parse::CPAN::Meta version 1.44 required--this is only version 1.40 at /usr/lib/perl5/5.8.8/CPAN/Meta/Converter.pm line 13.**

To be able to update Parse::CPAN::Meta, I had to first disable the use of CPAN::Meta in MakeMaker. I edited the file:
**/usr/lib/perl5/5.8.8/ExtUtils/MM_Any.pm**
And added "**return 0;**" after "**sub _has_cpan_meta {**" to make:
**sub _has_cpan_meta {

return 0;**

Then I was able to install Parse::CPAN::Meta as normal with "**cpan Parse::CPAN::Meta**". After which I confirmed CPAN::Meta was working "**perl -MCPAN::Meta**" and removed the "**return 0**" I'd added to **/usr/lib/perl5/5.8.8/ExtUtils/MM_Any.pm**.

Hey presto, all working again :)

Hope that helps anyone else who finds this thread.

Answer (score 0):

If you've the error (as per comment about `perl -MCPAN::Meta -e1`):

> version version 0.82 required--this is only version 0.78

then try upgrading it:

```
cpan CPAN::Meta
```

---

If you don't have access to install perl packages globally, run `cpan` and execute:

```
cpan> look CPAN::Meta
```

which will open a subshell in a distribution's directory, so you can download CPAN tar.gz manually and extract it there.

<sup>Source: [Issues with installing Inline::Python](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=1034401)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

The up to date 'version' is here: https://metacpan.org/pod/version

ExtUtils::MakeMaker contains a stripped down version which says:

> This is a modified copy of version.pm 0.9909, bundled exclusively for
>   use by ExtUtils::Makemaker and its dependencies to bootstrap when
>   version.pm is not available.

But in the code it says:
$VERSION = '7.36';

Answer (score -1):

Try finding the location of CPAN::Meta and delete it or back it up and then try installing it again.